# Is there any way to import a png into python using only modules that come with python 3?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, image-processing, tkinter

I want to import a png using tkinter. I have seen many tutorials to use PhotoImage but it does not accept the .png file format. Moreover, I cannot use Pillow as this program is for use in my school and my school only has the modules that come with python. Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: why not just convert your .png to .gif? That seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Why not just install pillow? All it takes it a little `pip install pillow` or are there restrictions at your school?

Comment: Have you tried using a .png? The latest tkinter supports .png files.

Comment: See [Built-in PNG Image Support](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html). What does `tkinter.TkVersion` return?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter only supports 3 file formats off the bat which are GIF, PGM, and PPM. You will need to convert the files to .GIF then load them in using tkinter.

There are libraries such as Python Imaging Library (PIL), however it might not be allowed in your school to use it.

Hopefully your school allows Photoshop, GIMP or any image editing software to allow you to convert, but I am sure there are plenty of online programs.

Comment: tkinter _does_ support .PNG if the Tk it uses is 8.6+. As 8.6 has [Built-in PNG Image Support](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html).